# send mail, compatible with oauth security protocol

Tags: android, android-studio

I just received an email from google informing me that as of May 30, 2022, the option to allow access to less secure applications in google will no longer be available. Therefore, the old application that I had to send mails from Android will no longer work. I have searched the internet and I have found this code that in theory is compatible with the oauth2 protocol and I have tested it. But if I deactivate the access permission to insecure applications, it gives me an identification error. Do you detect any problem in this code? This is the code:

mainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button boton;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        boton=findViewById(R.id.button);
        boton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                new Thread(new Runnable(){
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            GMailSender sender = new GMailSender("mymail@gmail.com", "mypassword");
                            sender.sendMail("This is Subject",
                                    "This is Body",
                                    "mymail@gmail.com",
                                    "othermail@gmail.com");

                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            Log.e("SendMail", e.getMessage(), e);
                        }
                    }
                }).start();

            }
        });
    }
}
```

GmailSender:

```
public class GMailSender extends javax.mail.Authenticator{
    private String mailhost = "smtp.gmail.com";
    private String user;
    private String password;
    private Session session;

    static {
        Security.addProvider(new JSSEProvider());
    }

    public GMailSender(String user, String password) {
        this.user = user;
        this.password = password;

        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.setProperty("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
        props.setProperty("mail.host", mailhost);
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class",
                "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");
        props.setProperty("mail.smtp.quitwait", "false");

        session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, this);
    }

    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
        return new PasswordAuthentication(user, password);
    }

    public synchronized void sendMail(String subject, String body, String sender, String recipients) throws Exception {
        try{
            MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
            DataHandler handler = new DataHandler(new ByteArrayDataSource(body.getBytes(), "text/plain"));
            message.setSender(new InternetAddress(sender));
            message.setSubject(subject);
            message.setDataHandler(handler);
            if (recipients.indexOf(',') > 0)
                message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(recipients));
            else
                message.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(recipients));
            Transport.send(message);
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.i("error",e.toString());
        }
    }

    public class ByteArrayDataSource implements DataSource {
        private byte[] data;
        private String type;

        public ByteArrayDataSource(byte[] data, String type) {
            super();
            this.data = data;
            this.type = type;
        }

        public ByteArrayDataSource(byte[] data) {
            super();
            this.data = data;
        }

        public void setType(String type) {
            this.type = type;
        }

        public String getContentType() {
            if (type == null)
                return "application/octet-stream";
            else
                return type;
        }

        public InputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {
            return new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
        }

        public String getName() {
            return "ByteArrayDataSource";
        }

        public OutputStream getOutputStream() throws IOException {
            throw new IOException("Not Supported");
        }
    }
}
```

and the class  jsseprovider:

```
public final class JSSEProvider extends Provider {

    public JSSEProvider() {
        super("HarmonyJSSE", 1.0, "Harmony JSSE Provider");
        AccessController.doPrivileged(new java.security.PrivilegedAction<Void>() {
            public Void run() {
                put("SSLContext.TLS",
                        "org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.SSLContextImpl");
                put("Alg.Alias.SSLContext.TLSv1", "TLS");
                put("KeyManagerFactory.X509",
                        "org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.KeyManagerFactoryImpl");
                put("TrustManagerFactory.X509",
                        "org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.TrustManagerFactoryImpl");
                return null;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Please do not put hardcoded email credentials in an app (or a Stack Overflow question, for that matter). All you are doing is creating security problems for you and spam/phishing problems for the rest of the planet. Either use `ACTION_SEND` (and let the user send the email through their preferred email client) or have your app securely talk to your Web service to send the email.

Comment: I have activated two factor authentication in gmail and I have the password for my application, but I can't find any example that uses this method.

Answer (score 0):

Simply create an app password in your google account and use this password in your old app. It works for me, it should work for you too.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).